# A clicking bot like .click

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would you use jQuery to check a checkbox, like for a bot in example you would have a button keep getting clicked, what function can you use to click the button using its ID without doing in manually .

Comment: if my answer solves your question please accept the the answer for future users

Answer (score 2):

You can check or uncheck a checkbox element or a radio button using the .prop() method:

```
$( "#x" ).prop( "checked", true );
```

for button you can just use .click()

```
 $("#x").click();
```